# U_REGEX_INVALID_CAPTURE_GROUP_NAME error occurs when trying to escape regex characters on Windows only

Tags: r, regex, escaping

I recently implemented a function to escape characters interpretable as regex that go into a system call for my R package 'rNOMADS'

```
SanitizeWGrib2Inputs <- function(check.strs) {
    #Escape regex characters before inputting to wgrib2
    #INPUTS
    #    CHECK.STRS - Strings possibly containing regex metacharacters
    #OUTPUTS
    #    CHECKED.STRS - Strings with metacharacters appropriately escaped

    meta.chars <- paste0("\\", c("(", ")", ".", "+", "*", "^", "$", "?", "[", "]", "|"))

   for(k in 1:length(meta.chars)) {
       check.strs <- stringr::str_replace(check.strs, meta.chars[k], paste0("\\\\", meta.chars[k]))
   }

   checked.strs <- check.strs

   return(checked.strs)
}
```

and I include an example in my package documentation:

```
check.strs <- c("frank", "je.rry", "har\\old", "Johnny Ca$h")
checked.strs <- SanitizeWGrib2Inputs(check.strs)
```

This works fine on my ubuntu machine and passed the CRAN checks.  However, when I uploaded the package to CRAN, their windows checker said:

```
> check.strs <- c("frank", "je.rry", "har\\old", "Johnny Ca$h")
> checked.strs <- SanitizeWGrib2Inputs(check.strs) Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :    Invalid capture group name. (U_REGEX_INVALID_CAPTURE_GROUP_NAME) Calls: SanitizeWGrib2Inputs -> <Anonymous> -> stri_replace_first_regex -> .Call Execution halted
** running examples for arch 'x64' ... ERROR Running examples in 'rNOMADS-Ex.R' failed The error most likely occurred in:

> base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
> ### Name: SanitizeWGrib2Inputs
> ### Title: Make sure regex metacharacters are properly escaped
> ### Aliases: SanitizeWGrib2Inputs
> ### Keywords: internal
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> 
> check.strs <- c("frank", "je.rry", "har\\old", "Johnny Ca$h")
> checked.strs <- SanitizeWGrib2Inputs(check.strs) Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :    Invalid capture group name. (U_REGEX_INVALID_CAPTURE_GROUP_NAME) Calls: SanitizeWGrib2Inputs -> <Anonymous> -> stri_replace_first_regex -> .Call Execution halted
```

I verified this behavior on my Windows partition.  What is the work around for this?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and I'm getting the same error that you get on Windows.

Comment: Are you just trying to replicate a Regex escape feature to match special chars as literal ones? You can do it as a one liner actually.

Comment: You may escape the chars using `str_replace_all(check.strs, "[{\\[\\]()|?$^*+.\\\\]", "\\$0")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple `str_replace_all` to escape all the special regex metacharacters:

```
SanitizeWGrib2Inputs <- function(check.strs) {
    return(str_replace_all(check.strs, "[{\\[()|?$^*+.\\\\]", "\\$0"))
}
check.strs <- c("frank", "je.rry", "har\\old", "Johnny Ca$h")
checked.strs <- SanitizeWGrib2Inputs(check.strs) 
checked.strs
## => [1] "frank"         "je\\.rry"      "har\\\\old"    "Johnny Ca\\$h"
```

**Notes**:

- The `"[{\\[\\]()|?$^*+.\\\\]` (actually, `"[{\[\]()|?$^*+.\\]`) will match any single char, either `{`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `|`, `?`, `$`, `^`, `*`, `+`, `.` or `\`
- The `"\\$0"` replacement will change each of the chars into `\` + the same char (the `$0` is the backreference to the whole match value).
- I do not think you need to add `]` here since outside a character class it is not a special character if there is no paired opening `[` in front.

Comment: Curiously, I still had failures in Windows even using your answer, until I upgraded to R 3.3.3 and installed the latest version of stringr. In any case, it works now, many thanks!

Comment: @glossarch: That is really strange. There are problems with using the zeroth group backreference, maybe a better idea is to use a capturing group - `return(str_replace_all(check.strs, "([{\\[()|?$^*+.\\\\])", "\\$1"))`. Also, that approach would also work with `gsub` - `gsub("([{\\[()|?$^*+.\\\\])", "\\\\\\1", s)`.