# Extracting sub strings in order

Tags: r, regex, string

I have strings similar to this:

```
the.string <- "982y987r0jhABCdioy2093uiwhf"
```

I also have a vector of substrings such as this:

```
the.substrings <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "987")
```

I would like to form a new vector, containing only the occurrences of the first 2 of `the.substrings` that occur in `the.string`, in the order that they occur. So in the above example, we just want `"987"` and `"ABC"` **in that order.**

I have implemented this, with the following algorithm:

1. Loop over each of `the.substrings` and search for an occurrence of each one.
2. If it occurs, save the substring and the position in which it occurs.
3. On exiting the loop use the positions saved in step 2 to order the occurrences:

---

```
mod.str <- list(2)
pos.str <- numeric(2)
n <- 1

for (i in 1:length(the.substrings)) {
  reg.search <- gregexpr(the.substrings[i], the.string)
  if(reg.search[[1]][1] > 0) {
    mod.str[n] <- the.substrings[i]
    pos.str[n] <- reg.search[[1]][1]
    n <- n + 1
  }
}

dtfoo <- as.data.frame(cbind(mod.str, pos.str))
dtfoo <- as.data.frame(lapply(dtfoo, unlist))

as.character(dtfoo[order(dtfoo$pos.str),][, 1])
```

which seems to work OK:

```
[1] "987" "ABC"
```

However I am wondering if there is a better (more efficient, less error-prone, perhaps utilising a functional programming approach) way to achieve this ?

Comment: Maybe `regmatches(the.string, gregexpr(paste(the.substrings, collapse="|"), the.string))`?

Comment: You may use that solution above as is if your `the.substrings` are only alphanumeric, are they?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, only alphanumeric

Comment: Ok, this solution  has already been posted by snoram.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually I prefer your solution as it does not rely on external packages. If you write it as an answer I will upvote and accept :)

Comment: I will, but I think there is a potential issue with the approach, I will post a corrected one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK great - I will be interested in knowing what the potential issue is !

Comment: Well, I have just understood that my solution is actually correct, but snoram's is not - I will explain now in my answer. If you want, try his code with `the.string <- "ABCDE982y987r0jhABCdioy2093uiwhf"` and `the.substrings <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "987", "ABCDE")`

Comment: I posted an [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634348/3832970). Sorry, it is a bit long, but I found out the TRE regex engine behaves as most POSIX regex engines when it comes to alternation group parsing and decided to explain the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following base R solution:

```
regmatches(the.string, gregexpr(paste(the.substrings, collapse="|"), the.string))
```

The point is that you use `the.substrings` to build a regex comprising *alternatives* joined with a `|` [*alternation operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), and the `regmatches` / `gregexpr` will extract all the occurrences of the pattern in the input in the order they appear, from left to right.

The pattern will look like `ABC|DEF|GHI|987|ABCDE` if `the.substrings` is `c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "987", "ABCDE")`. Since the regex engine used in this `gregexpr` call is **TRE**, the alternation pattern is matched in the way described in the [*Text-Directed Engine Returns the Longest Match* section at regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager):

> When a text-directed engine attempts `Get|GetValue|Set|SetValue` on `SetValue`, it tries all permutations of the regex at the start of the string. It does so efficiently, without any backtracking. It sees that the regex can find a match at the start of the string, and that the matched text can be either `Set` or `SetValue`. Because the text-directed engine evaluates the regex as a whole, it has no concept of one alternative being listed before another. But it has to make a choice as to which match to return. It always returns the longest match, in this case `SetValue`.

If you use the same approach (with `paste(the.substrings, collapse="|")`) using *`stringr::str_extract_all`* you may end up with a different set of matches because in the ICU regex engine there checks for alternatives in the way described in the *Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager* section. The main point is that when a matching alternative is found, the rest (to the right) is not even tried. You may easily see that if you run the following code:

```
> the.string <- "ABCDE982y987r0jhABCdioy2093uiwhf"
> the.substrings <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "987", "ABCDE")
> str_extract_all(the.string, str_c(the.substrings, collapse = "|"))
[[1]]
[1] "ABC" "987" "ABC"

> regmatches(the.string, gregexpr(paste(the.substrings, collapse="|"), the.string))
[[1]]
[1] "ABCDE" "987"   "ABC"
```

Since `ABC` is before `ABCDE`, `stringr::str_extract_all` returns the `ABC` match (`DE` does not match any of the alternatives, it is skipped), and `gregexpr` checks all possible matches and returns the longest, `ABCDE`.

Also, see the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/ugFJOZ).

Comment: Fantastic answer ! I will wait for it to get a few more upvotes before accepting,

Comment: One more consideration: if `the.substrings` contain special chars, you will need to escape them before using in an alternation. The code for `stringr` ICU patterns is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43001518/3832970) (`SanitizeWGrib2Inputs`) and a base R escaping function can be taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947825/3832970) (`regex.escape`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use functions from `stringr` like this:

```
library(stringr)
```

First extract the locations of the strings which are matched

```
string.locations <- str_locate(the.string, the.substrings)
string.locations 
#      start end
# [1,]    12  14
# [2,]    NA  NA
# [3,]    NA  NA
# [4,]     5   7
```

The order them by starting point and extract only the first two:

```
string.locations <- string.locations[order(string.locations[, 1]), ]
string.locations.sub <- string.locations[1:2, ]
string.locations.sub 
#      start end
# [1,]     5   7
# [2,]    12  14
```

And then subset the original string only by those positions:

```
str_sub(the.string, string.locations.sub)
# [1] "987" "ABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(the.string, str_c(the.substrings, collapse = "|"))[[1]][1:2]
[1] "987" "ABC"
```